# Function for converting from T to const T in C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, stl, constants

I want to allow constant or non-constant iteration over a container class I wrote. My container stores elements in a `std::vector` of non-`const` references (call it `elements`). I'm using Boost's [transform iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to do this, e.g.:

```
auto begin() const
{
    return boost::make_transform_iterator
        ( elements.begin()
        , to_const<std::reference_wrapper<ElementType>>
        );
}
```

Here I'm using a simple function template I wrote to convert an object of type `T` to `const T`:

```
template <typename T>
std::add_const<T>::type to_const(T value) { return value; }
```

I know it's trivial to write, but I just wanted to know if there's already an STL or Boost function template to do this, akin to `std::add_const` but as an actual function. (Alternatively, if anyone knows of a better way to lazily convert a vector of mutables to a vector of constants, that would be even better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, there is a `<utility>` template function to do that, [`std::as_const<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const), and BTW, this (below) isn't how to write it.

```
template <typename T>
std::add_const<T>::type to_const(T value) { return value; }
```

You are taking the argument by value which allows temporaries, and may require invocation of copy/move constructors; rather, use `lvalue` reference (aka, the object cannot be a temporary) as prototyped below:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::add_const<T>::type& as_const(T& t) noexcept{
    return t;
}
```

or

```
template <typename T>
constexpr std::add_const_t<T>& as_const(T& t) noexcept{ return t; }
```

Comment: Perfect. My forgetting things like constexpr and reference parameters is why I wanted to find a standard implementation. :P

Comment: For completeness, it should be said that this *does* allow temporaries, if they are `const`, as arguments.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, Since this isn't a Forwarding Reference, temporaries can only be accepted if explicit template arguments were given like [`std::as_const<const T>(A())` **or ...** `std::as_const(static_cast<const A&>(A()));`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77d58c9af7e711af)... But why will someone even want to do that??

Comment: @WhiZTiM i am saying that if the temporary is `const`, no explicit template argument is necessary. Qt has some functions that return const temporaries, for example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d-1 .

Comment: This answers my question, but I thought it worth mentioning that I ended up not being able to use this solution for my particular problem. The issue is that if I try to pass std::as_const<> as a functor, it can't tell which overload to use, even with type-casting. So I ended up just using lambdas instead.

Comment: @JonathanSharman, I am not sure I understand. Can you post an example on Coliru and link it in your next comment?

Comment: I don't know how to get g++ to compile `std::as_const`, but here's a snippet: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f82ed9fed4e1b521

In VC++, I get an error saying it can't determine which overload of `as_const` to use.